# Ninject Factory: Create the appropriate class based on a parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, ninject

I have 3 classes:

1. `class SqlQueryService : IQueryService`
2. `class FileQueryService : IQueryService`
3. `class NCRFileQueryService : FileQueryService`

I have create an interface factory:

```
public interface IQueryServiceFactory
{
    IQueryService Create(string connection);
}
```

In the application module:

```
Bind(typeof(IQueryService)).To(typeof(SqlQueryService)).Named("Data Source");         
Bind(typeof(IQueryService)).To(typeof(NCRFileQueryService)).Named("NCR File Source");
Bind(typeof(IQueryService)).To(typeof(FileQueryService)).Named("File Source");

Bind<IQueryServiceFactory>().ToFactory();
```

In my app I want to create an instance of one of three classes based on a parameter like the following:

```
IQueryService queryService =
    _queryServiceFactory.Create(_configuration.SelectedTPV.Connection);
```

- If the string parameter starts with "Data Source" create a `SqlQueryService`
- If the string parameter starts with "File Source" create a `FileQueryService`
- If the string parameter starts with "NCR File Source" create a `NCRFileQueryService`

It's possible to do that?

*Note: My app is a winforms app with .NET Framework 3.5 because is for and OLD windows

The Ninject version that I use is 3.2.2.0 and the version of the Ninject Extensions Factory is 3.2.1.0

Comment: Is your configuration value `_configuration.SelectedTPV.Connection` a fixed value that doesn't change at runtime, or does that value actually change while the application is running? In either case however, you don't need the factory. Removing `IQueryServiceFactory` will improve your design.

Comment: The configuration value is setup on a website and can be more than one. Then the user download the app login with his credentials and then the app will connect to an api to get the configuration values. Then the user can choose from a dropdown. If I remove IQueryServiceFactory how can I create the concrete class based on configuration value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom instance provider and then binding your factory like:

```
this.Bind<IQueryServiceFactory>()
    .ToFactory(() => new UseFirstArgumentAsNameInstanceProvider());
```

See [Treating the first factory method parameter as a name specifier](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-Referencing-Named-Bindings#example-customisation-treating-the-first-factory-method-parameter-as-a-name-specifier) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Since the value you supply to the factory is not a *user supplied* value, it is not needed to complicate the consuming code with:

- That configuration value
- The factory abstraction

Instead of depending on `IQueryServiceFactory`, the consumer should simply depend on `IQueryService`. How to supply the consumer with the correct implementation, depends on your application's needs, but there are two options.

#### Option 1: The configuration value is known at start-up time (before the DI Container is configured)

When the configuration value is known at start-up, before the DI Container is configured, this simply means you only have to register one implementation in the container based on that value.

For instance:

```
Bind(typeof(IQueryService),
    value == "Data Source" ? typeof(SqlQueryService) :
    value == "NCR File Source ? typeof(NCRFileQueryService) :
    value == "File Source" ? typeof(FileQueryService) :
    throw new InvalidOperationException(value));
```

#### Option 2: The configuration value is known after, or can change during the lifetime of the application

Even in case the configuration value isn't fixed or known at startup, there is still no reason to use a factory abstraction and let the consumer depend on that configuration value. This can all be hidden behind the `IQueryService` abstraction by creating a Proxy:

```
public class ConfigurationSelectorQueryServiceProxy : IQueryService
{
    private readonly IQueryService a;
    private readonly IQueryService b;
    private readonly IQueryService c;
    public ConfigurationSelectorQueryServiceProxy(
        SqlQueryService a, NCRFileQueryService b, FileQueryService c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    // IQueryService methods. Forward the call to one of the wrapped services
    public object SomeMethod(object args) => GetService().SomeMethod(args);

    // Helper methods
    private IQueryService GetService() =>
        // Read configuration value
        GetService(_configuration.SelectedTPV.Connection);

    private IQueryService GetService(string value) =>
        value == "Data Source" ? (this.a :
        value == "NCR File Source ? this.b :
        value == "File Source" ? this.c :
        throw new InvalidOperationException(value);        
}
```

This `ConfigurationSelectorQueryServiceProxy` Proxy implementation can be registered as `IQueryService` and injected into consumers. This way consumers don't have to know about the complexity of selecting the right implementation. They can simply use the `IQueryService` abstraction.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your point so in that way now just have to register only the proxy class as IQueryService and in the consumer class inject it as the other services, yes I think this is more clean :-), so when to use the factory?

Comment: I finf the use for factories quite low. In case the value comes from the user, there might be more use for a factory, but even then your should consider a mediator/delegator approach first, before creating a factory.

Answer (score 1):

thanks Owen!

I read the wiki but I didn't realize of that customisation.

Finally I resolved adding a class like:

```
public class QueryServiceInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override string GetName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        string connection = arguments[0].ToString();

        return connection.Split('=')[0];
    }

    protected override Ninject.Parameters.IConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        return base.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
}
```

and in the application module:

```
Bind(typeof(IQueryService)).To(typeof(SqlQueryService)).Named("Data Source");         
Bind(typeof(IQueryService)).To(typeof(NCRFileQueryService)).Named("NCR File Source");
Bind(typeof(IQueryService)).To(typeof(FileQueryService)).Named("File Source");

Bind<IQueryServiceFactory>().ToFactory(() => new QueryServiceInstanceProvider());
```